# SMBus Host Controller not enables

Tags: linux, debian, kali-linux, vmware

*i got this error when i starting up kali linux on vmware*

### [    1.1709975] piix4_smbus 0000:00:07.3: SMBus Host Controller not enabled!
BusyBox v1.35.0 (Debian 1:1.35.0-2) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of Built-in commands.

*what can i do please help me*

Comment: VMware does not really emulate a PIIX4 chipset chipset SMBus controller. In a physical machine, it could be used to read the specifications of the RAM memory modules, and/or to access some hardware monitoring chips. Both of these functions are not needed in the virtual machine, so the message `SMBus Host Controller not enabled!` is normal and expected in VMware, so you can ignore that message.

Comment: The fact that Kali is dropping into BusyBox shell indicates it is failing to find its root filesystem and/or the disk controller it needs to access the root filesystem. Since you have chosen to use Kali Linux, a professional penetration testing toolkit, you could treat this as an elementary penetration exercise into an unknown Linux system that initially offers you only a limited set of tools. Figure out the capabilities of the system (= which drivers are available) and adjust the configuration of VMware to match that whenever possible. Then the system should be able to boot further. Repeat.